# open shortcut on A drive to file on E drive

Tags: windows, macros

Create a shortcut on desktop to data file on another hard drive. I need to be able to correct parts and update data thru the shortcut. Connects where I view but Keeps telling me unable to update file. If I try it and open it does not update. using libreoffice 7.4

Comment: Your post is unclear, and it is not certain you have presented a specific question. If your first language is not English, that is fine, but you may want to try rephrasing your question or using a different translator tool to see if that improves things. Otherwise, you need to read your post, recognize that we only know about you and your problem what you tell us. What kind of file is this? Shortcuts don't usually "update" the target files, unless the "shortcuts" are scripted or coded.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much info, but here are two possibilities:

- If using an *external* HDD, it might take too long for the drive to spin up. Test that using an app like [KeepAliveHD](https://github.com/stsrki/KeepAliveHD). If the link works while the drive is up, then keep the drive from spinning down (sleeping).
- If using a *network* drive, edit the shortcut to use the full UNC path.